# How to render views in compile time in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, custom-renderer

I'm trying to render some controls myself in the compile time. Meaning that i'm trying to create for instance a `Xamarin.Forms.Button` and get it's native `Windows.UI.Xaml.Control.Button`image (or `FormsButton` to be accurate)all in compile time.

I was trying to apply this on a `ContentView` so by applying this theory, this is the code to accomplish that:

```
var contentView = Element.Content;
var renderer = contentView.GetOrCreateRenderer();
var nativeControl = renderer.ContainerLayout;
```

By doing so i get a native UWP `FrameworkElement` with all the properties of the `ContentView` like the background and so on. However, i don't get the children rendered. That actually makes sense because basically you render just the `ContentView`. But i have no idea how to render all it's children. Hope that the solution applies to any XamarinForms control that has a `Children` (or a `Content`) property

Comment: Do you means that you want to get the all the sub element of ContentView in native renderer?

Comment: Yes, I want to render the ContentView and all of it's children just like what XamarinForms does at runtime.

Comment: Have you used [Visual Tree Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) in uwp?

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understand that. An example would be useful. A XamarinForms example since i will be creating renderers for the 3 platforms

Comment: The Visual Tree Helper is used to get the children element from their container. but it only available in uwp platform.

Comment: So is there any UWP solution?

Comment: As far as I know it is only way.

Comment: But how would XamarinForms does it? You create the layout and start adding children they are rendererd  at runtime for each platform.

Comment: This is [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) open source project, for adding children is realize via 
Layout  Renderer.